# Saving high score and other things - corona

Tags: json, lua, save, coronasdk

I want to save a high score in my game. I saw that you need to use json library but I dont know how to use it. i want to save a table and not just a written text. Ther is an easy way of doing that?

adit:
I have found Ego: 
http://techority.com/2011/12/28/ego-easy-saving-and-loading-in-your-corona-apps/
it works very good! but I am concern. i am not Savvy at thise things. someone can the me if it is Reliable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve your problem in a easier way..

Just declare a Variable for the Score like this..

```
local score=0
```

Then Increment the score variable by 1 whenever it hits the paddle. So Insert the coding in Collision Function as given below:

```
  local function onCollision(event)
  {
  score=score+1
  }
 ball.collision=onCollision
 ball:addEventListener("collision",ball)
```

Finally When you need to save your highscore (after gameover), You can use Preference instead of json which makes the larger coding.

```
local preference= require "preference"
local highscore=0

 preference.save{highscore=score}
```

If you want to display the Highscore, then use the following:

```
highscore_value=preference.getValue("highscore")
display.newText(highscore_value,0,0,nil,30)
```

This might be useful for your problem !!

Refer here :[Save highscore on corona sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17782311/save-highscore-on-corona-sdk)