# Corona : score keep running/ save it and show it after

Tags: lua, coronasdk, scoring

My score doesn't stop when my main object hits an obstacle (keeps running on the storyboard restart and start screen). I want it to stop and be able to save it and show it to the gamer next time (even share it on facebook if it's possible ). an image will pop out where the player can find its best score ever, and his current score.

```
score = 0


local scoreNumber = display.newText(score, 200, 0, nil, 50)
scoreNumber.xScale = 1.2
scoreNumber.yScale = 1.2

local function updateScore()
score = score + 1
scoreNumber.text = score
end

timer.performWithDelay(100, updateScore, -1)

local scoreText = display.newText("score:", 0, 0, nil, 50)
scoreText.xScale = 1.2
scoreText.yScale = 1.2

end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You know when to stop the score, so

```
 score = 0
 local scoreTimer

 local scoreNumber = display.newText(score, 200, 0, nil, 50)
 scoreNumber.xScale = 1.2
 scoreNumber.yScale = 1.2

 local function updateScore()
   score = score + 1
   scoreNumber.text = score
 end

scoreTimer = timer.performWithDelay(100, updateScore, -1)

 local scoreText = display.newText("score:", 0, 0, nil, 50)
 scoreText.xScale = 1.2
 scoreText.yScale = 1.2

end
```

so once the game is over cancel the timer using timer.cancel(scoreTimer). To save your score use check it here ,

[Save highscore on corona sdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17782311/save-highscore-on-corona-sdk)